# mySQL workbench hangs after connecting to database

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL workbench 6.3 CE to connect to mysql database on amazon aws (rds) system.  I was running a create table query that was taking too long (lot of joins), and I stopped the query, and closed the workbench from Task Manager (end process).  Since that operation:
1) I can open the workbench connect to the database, but once I connect and select any table from the schema, the workbench hangs. 
2) No query could be run from workbench - I have to stop the query and I get the error "Interrupt:  Error 2006, Mysql server has gone away".
3) if I click on the table name in the object browser, I don't see any columns for the table.

I tried to run the queries from the command line (in the workbench, right click on the database connection and click "Start command line client" - and here, I am able to run queries without issue.  However, I have connected to this database through RODBC - in R, none of the odbcCommands are working (sqlTables() hangs, etc).

I am at my wits end trying to understand whats wrong - any pointers would be wonderful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realized it was because I stopped the create table query - I don't know the mechanics, but apparently, there was a background process running.  I had to kill the query and kill the connection and everything was back to normal.

Hope this helps someone some other time.

Comment: Any explanation on how you did this??

Comment: I was looking in the MySQL workbench where it lists all the active connections and queries.  I could kill the connection and query from here.  I apologise I can't provide more detail